# Handle multiple buttons onClick event React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have an array with button names. I map through them and render them. I would like to add an `onClick` event that would handle them.
Those buttons are filters, so onClick event should trigger a filter function, but also I would like to change the styling, to show what filter is clicked now.

This is what I have for now:

[-] A list of buttons

```
const STATUS = ['All procurements', 'Draft', 'Running', 'Completed'];
```

[image]

[-] The mapping and styling

```
{STATUS.map(status => (
  <button
     className={`flex w-full btn justify-between hover:bg-primary-300 mb-2 cursor-pointer ${
               isActiveFilter ? 'hover:bg-primary-500 bg-primary-400' : '' }` }
     key={status}
     onClick={handleFilterClick}
     value={status.toLowerCase()}
   >
         {status}
         {isActiveFilter && <UilCheck />}
   </button>
 ))}
```

[-] And the `handleFilterClick` function:

```
const [isActiveFilter, setIsActiveFilter] = React.useState(false);

function handleFilterClick(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {
  setFilterStatus(e.currentTarget.value as FilterStatus);
  setIsActiveFilter(true);
}
```

Now when I click on a button, this is what I get:

[image]

But ideally I would like to get only the clicked button to be active.
So what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your procedure is right just you have to add some think:

```
const STATUS = ['All procurements', 'Draft', 'Running', 'Completed'];
const [isActiveFilter, setIsActiveFilter] = React.useState(''); // string which one is active

function handleFilterClick(v) {
  setIsActiveFilter(v);
}

{STATUS.map(status => (
  <button
     className={`flex w-full btn justify-between hover:bg-primary-300 mb-2 
cursor-pointer ${
               isActiveFilter === status  ? 'hover:bg-primary-500 bg-primary-400' : '' }` }
     key={status}
     onClick={handleFilterClick(status)}
     
   >
         {status}
         {status === isActiveFilter && <UilCheck />}
   </button>
 ))}
```

base on isActiveFilter value you can add active class also

Comment: yep, I was looking for a way to compare the current button value to the status so I could set it active. Thanks!

Comment: how could I make the first button (all procurements) active by default, when no buttons were clicked?

Comment: if your array i fixed then you can use this const [isActiveFilter, setIsActiveFilter] = React.useState(STATUS[0]);